Odoo: How to open record on new tab by clicking a link with icon
ers:
I want to open a record from a list view on a new tab.
I tried making a computed char field making an URL and put a widget="url" but it put the whole link as a text making the cell too big. So I just want an icon like  that opens the record in a new tab or the user can copy the link by right click.

Here is what worked for me.

Make a computed HTML field with building the link like this:

link = fields.Html(compute='_compute_link')

def _compute_link(self):
   for rec in self:
      rec.link = f"""<a href="/mail/view?model={self._name}&res_id={rec.id} target="_blank"><i class="oi oi-launch" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"/></a>"""


Put the field widget HTML on the list view.

<field name="link" nolabel="1"/>
Notes:

I'm using /mail/view the same as a link is given on notification emails, avoid putting action id since it can change over every DB/code.
If you don't include stop propagation on the link, it will open the record on that tab (as expected click on the cell).


Normally I leave it up to the user how he wants to deal with a link or a URL. My tool of choice is the middle mouse button (greetings to Apple users).
Apart from that, a tip for your implementation: Use an HTML field right away, then you don't need to use the widget in the view.

I considered it, I think making an HTML field would create jsonb columns on the table, I don't think it is needed since a simple varchar is enough

I meant, if you go for storing the field.

No, translatable fields are using jsonb in database.
